# SQL - How to get only current and previous value for each ID

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table

```
id, date, value
a,  5/22/2019, 22
b,  5/22/2019, 22
c,  5/22/2019, 22
a,  5/21/2019, 21
b,  5/21/2019, 21
c,  5/21/2019, 21
a,  5/20/2019, 20
b,  5/20/2019, 20
c,  5/20/2019, 20
```

Want to get ID and value of current (latest) and previous date:

```
id, date, date-1
a, 22, 21
b, 22, 21
c, 22, 21
```

So far I have some parts but need only 1 ID per row (this bellow give more than 1 row for each ID - it will show for 5/20 date in the next row for the same ID which is wrong):

```
select 
    id, value,
    lag(value, 1, 0) over (partition by id order by date ) as "date - 1"
from 
    table1
```

How to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try like below

```
with cte as
(
select 
    id, value,
    lag(value, 1, 0) over (partition by id order by date ) as "date - 1",
    lag(value, 2, 0) over (partition by id order by date ) as "date - 2",
    row_number() over(partition by id order by date desc) rn
from 
    table1
) select * from cte where rn=1
```

Comment: Logic sounds good but `rn` shows as some random starting number (e.g. starts from 457, 458, 459 for a specific ID)... Maybe some group by is needed or a way to reset `rn` to 1 for each ID..

Comment: it will start always from 1 for each id as i have used parition by id

Comment: Never mind - found that need to add ORDER BY in different direction in order to start from latest date and therefore assign '1' for latest (`row_number() over(partition by id order by date DESC) rn`

Answer (score 2):

How about this? Note that I named the column `ddate` instead of date:

```sql
create table a_test(id varchar(1), ddate date, value int);

insert into a_test values ('a',  '5/22/2019', 22),
                          ('b',  '5/22/2019', 22),
                          ('c',  '5/22/2019', 22),
                          ('a',  '5/21/2019', 21),
                          ('b',  '5/21/2019', 21),
                          ('c',  '5/21/2019', 21),
                          ('a',  '5/20/2019', 20),
                          ('b',  '5/20/2019', 20),
                          ('c',  '5/20/2019', 20);

with cte as(
select id,
       value,
       row_number() over(partition by id order by ddate desc) as rn
from a_test)

select id,
       MAX(value) FILTER (WHERE rn = 1) as col1,
       MAX(value) FILTER (WHERE rn = 2) as col2
from cte
group by id
```